# Normal CPU Usage But Slow Jetty Response Time During Peak Hour

Tags: jetty, cpu, cpu-usage

We have several web servers running jetty to serve 100 request per second.

During peak hour, the response time of the jetty becomes slow and the number of request that the jetty handled is dropped.

We have checked that 
- The cpu usage of the jetty is around 20-30% which is healthy. 
- IO figure is normal
- no slow query in our DB and the DB server is healthy too.
- network is healthy.

By adding more web servers, the problem is solved.

But I don't understand why the CPU usage is not rised when the web traffic loading is heavy?

Does anyone has similar experience?

Comment: Which OS?  This could be something as simple as a bad network driver version.  Or it might need more pool threads allocated.

Comment: We are using centos 5. I'm sure that the size of thread pool is enough. For bad network driver, I'm not sure. If it is network driver problem, How can I prove that? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I would obtain a NIC from a well know manufacturer/model, different than the one you are currently using, plug it in, install drivers, and give it a try.  One other thing to check, how much NIC traffic is going to and from the server?  Are you running full duplex?  Are there any errors reported at the switch on that port?

Comment: Thanks Brain2000 for your suggestion.I'm not good at linux system as I'm a programmer. I'm going to discuss with our system admin team about the issue.